# unable to Oauth twitter using tweepy

Tags: tweepy

please help, I feel like a total noob.

I'm trying to build a test twitter bot:

1. Oauth1.a is enabled.
2. I have the 4 needed keys (verified multiple times).
3. The app is authorized in my twitter account.

trying to run this code:

```
import tweepy

API_KEY="1234"
API_KEY_SECRET="5678"
ACCESS_TOKEN="9876"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET="badc0ffee"

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication Successful")
except:
    print("Authentication Error")
```

Constantly getting Authentication error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with the same code

Here is my new code, working:

```
import tweepy

api_key = "XXXXXXXX"
api_secret_key = "XXXXXX"
access_token = "XXXXXXX"
secret_access_token = "XXXXXX"

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=api_key, consumer_secret=api_secret_key,
    access_token=access_token, access_token_secret=secret_access_token
)
client.create_tweet(text='test')
```

You can find more examples at https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/API_v2/